# Should one be able to register the same device multiple times without getting a canoncial id on the "duplicate" registrations?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'v implemented the GCM, but have some points it seems I didn't follow understand.

GCM have a concept of Canonical Ids, in which if the client registers two or more times, and you from the server sends messages to these Google will return a (the) canonical id of the last registered regId ?? When I test this by deliberately not unregister the device it still successfully sends multiple messages to the same device. Have I misunderstood what the canonical id is? Are you suppose to be able to register the device several times ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can register the same app/device multiple times, and canonical Ids are designed to help you fix that problem when it arrives. Your server will need to prune your registration ID list when you receive a response with a canonical Id. You can see a response I wrote here: [android GCM get original id of canonical id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958079/android-gcm-get-original-id-of-canonical-id/13959022#13959022) That describes the format and what to do.

This post also contains good information about canonical Ids: [GCM and id handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752995/gcm-and-id-handling)